# reading only a column from disoriented excel file oledb

Tags: c#

I have been able to read a normal excel file via oledb, but the task file for my project contains various format issues, like multiple columns merged, a lot of cells under formulae among others, and as a result, the data set has been unable to store the data of excel file. If I manage to read contents of sheet- 'Input tab', cell numbers AF6-AF-24, my job is done, but the excel file is not getting parsed in excel at all, before i process the column out. Help please!

```
 OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection("Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=P:\\DummyTesterF.xlsx; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"");
             OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
             OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
             cmdExcel.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * From ['Input Tab$']");           


             cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
             Adapter.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
             DataTable Table = new DataTable();
             Adapter.Fill(Table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better switch to Office interop instead.